# Подскажите рабочий ли метод обучению программирования

Tags: c#

Вообщем я знаю основы c# могу написать простую, программу но так, то самостоятельно код писать не умею, сейчас переписываю дискорд бота разбираюсь в нем и учу его, очень сильно хочу научиться писать самостоятельно код и делать самостоятельно дискорд ботов, данный метод реален или нет подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Просто переписывать готовый код смысла не имеет. Но вы можете взять исходники готового бота и поменять под себя.

Comment: @tym32167 в каком смысле поменять под себя

Comment: @Артём добавить новый функционал или заменить текущий

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Переписывать чужой код смысла нет.
Надо написать свой.

Для обучения наилучший вариант выбрать какую-то несложную задача. И сделать её от начала до конца.

Этапы:

1. Придумать как это будет выглядеть и работать
2. Спроектировать код
3. Воплотить в жизнь
4. Выпустить в продакшен
5. Месяц стабильной работы в реальном мире

Лучше всего что бы задача была масштабируемая по масштабности и сложности. Тогда на этой задаче можно совершенствоваться и развиваться.

Если что-то делаешь сам то простраиваются нейронные связи на всех этапах процесса, начиная от задумки и до воплощения и поддержки в продакшен.

PS: Для твоей задачи хорошо подойдёт дискорд бот. Основу кода, заготовку можно взять откуда-то с GitHub но не более чем основу. И желательно что бы эта основа была как можно меньше, что бы не получилась обезьянья работа.

Comment: Я очень много изучаю и развиваю тему обучения программирования, могу по этой теме поделиться знаниями, напиши мне в приват, в профиле контакты, и благодарю за вопрос.